# Sort out custom post type alphabettically

Tags: wordpress, sorting, posts

A bit noob, I have been searching the net without a clue. I am trying to sort out this custom post (slider in my case) by alphabetical order, as you can see I have added the command to sort but it just ignores it and continues to display a random loop. What am I missing?

Thanks!

```
<?php 

/*
Template Name: Fullscreen Slideshow
*/

get_header(); 

$slide_loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => THEME_SLIDE_TYPE, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post__in' => 0,  'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
?>

<div id="fullscreenSlideshow">


<?php if ($slide_loop->have_posts()) : while ($slide_loop->have_posts()) : $slide_loop->the_post(); ?>

    <?php
        $slide_image_url =  wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
        $slide_text_position = (get_post_meta($post->ID, THEME_METABOX . "slide_text_position", true) == "") ? "left" : get_post_meta($post->ID, THEME_METABOX . "slide_text_position", true);
        $slide_color = (get_post_meta($post->ID, THEME_METABOX . "slide_color", true) == "") ? "light" : get_post_meta($post->ID, THEME_METABOX . "slide_color", true);
    ?>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="<?php echo $slide_image_url[0];?>" />
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="content <?php echo $slide_text_position; ?> <?php echo $slide_color; ?>">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <div class="caption"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>

<div id="slideshowNav">
    <div id="slideCount">
    </div>
    <div id="slideControls">
        <a id="slideprev" href="javascript:;"><?php _e("Prev", "ablaze");?></a>
        <a id="slidenext" href="javascript:;"><?php _e("Next", "ablaze");?></a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `post__in` from your arguments. Also have a look at the parameters which you can sort by (orderby) in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Just a note, never use capital letters in function names, custom post type names and taxonomy names. They are troublesome. Also, refrain from using numbers in the beginning of the name, and any special character (except the underscore `_`)